# One Redis call, Multiple command execution with return types

Tags: java, data-structures, architecture, redis

I need to execute following on Redis :

```
ZINTERSECT out 2 myset1 myset2
ZRANGE out 0 -1 (lets say it returns a set [20,30,40,50])
MGET user:20:blabla user:30:blabla user:40:blabla user:50:blabla (it returns [1,2,3,4])
ZRANGE blabla:1:value 0 -1
ZRANGE blabla:2:value 0 -1
ZRANGE blabla:3:value 0 -1
ZRANGE blabla:4:value 0 -1
```

This is the one transaction for my "list of lists" type structure. My Questions :

1- Is it possible to run it in one call ?

2- Should I use Transaction or Scripting for this ?

3- Is it feasible to run all these lines under high traffic without scripting or transaction features of Redis ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> 2 - Should I use Transaction or Scripting for this?

Since you to use the results of some commands in subsequent commands, a script is the way to go.

Lua scripts are generally fast. A script in Redis is also *transactional* by definition.

> 3 - Is it feasible to run all these lines under high traffic without scripting or transaction features of Redis ?

It depends on what you consider as "high traffic". Anyway, you should test and see if your approach is feasible. A simple Lua script will also be fast in most cases.

Most importantly you should consider the *time complexity* of each command you are going to use. These can be found in the [documentation of each command](http://redis.io/commands).

Comment: Thanks for reply. For the question 1, I need returned values. The lines that I wrote are not only write. The result of one is used in other. In this case how can it work with "one call" ? Doesn't it need to run the first one to get necessary set first ?

Comment: Only lua script can handle the situation that some commands depends on previous command's result.

Comment: I decided to use pipelined calls instead of scripting. The results of my stress tests are acceptable. I can handle the process with 2-3 calls. Is Lua script faster than pipelined approaches ?

Comment: @anL Nope. Some pipelined commands should be faster than the equivalent commands with a script.